# Check if an address is new or has been used already

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

Say, I have an address. I can check if it's watch-only by calling validateaddress. Is there such an easy way to check it that address is new or has been used already?

Answer (score 1):

maybe be a bit more specific, which client you use... I assume bitcoin core? In bitcoin core there is the command line interface (bitcoin-cli), that allows to send requests to the client. Specifications here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

"getreceivedbyaccount" or "getreceivedbyaddress" could do the jobe here.

Also, there are many blockchain "service" companies, which provide a web interface to look at the blockchain. For example:
https://blockchain.info/

On the top right you can enter an address, and see if you have already transactions used with it.

Comment: maybe you should read my question one more time -- RPC INTERFACE OF BITCOIN CORE!!!!!!!